# How to get the value displayed on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input in my page that uses WMIQuery to get the Version number of the OS. i.e Version 6.3.9600 is Windows 8.1. I am trying to use javascript to get that value and if it matches 6.3.9600 assign OSYS(Operating System Name) to Windows 8.1. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I cant get the site to populate the value. Am I doing this wrong?

OSVR(Operating System Version Number)

```
if (jQuery("#OSVR").val() == "6.3.9600") { 
  jQuery(input["name='OSYS']").val('Windows 8.1'); 
}
```

When I use the chrome dev tools. I get the OSYS value as Windows 8.1 but the OSVR value as false. Also I cant get the form to populate the value.

Comment: jQuery(#OSVR).val() chnage it to jQuery('#OSVR').val(), also make sure OSYS is id or name if it is name then

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: yes just a typo, if OSYS is name them compare using the name selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the quotes, just a type error

```
jQuery("#OSVR").val()

Change

if (jQuery(#OSVR).val() == "6.3.9600") {
}

To

if (jQuery("#OSVR").val() == "6.3.9600") {
}


if OSYS is name then

    if (jQuery(input["name='OSYS']").val() == "6.3.9600") {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes in [ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), if you exclude quotes then it should be some variable containing selector.

*Change*

```
if (jQuery(#OSVR).val() == "6.3.9600") {
```

*To*

```
if (jQuery("#OSVR").val() == "6.3.9600") {
```